# css absolute position + count element above

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is possible set position of absolute element with count height of element above? The goal is get elements with class `"pgafu-post-categories"` to one line above H2, when is different length.

```css
pgafu-post-categories {
  position: absolute;
  top: -82px;
  width: fit-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <h2>Small title</h2>
    <div class="pgafu-post-categories">category</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <h2>Long two <br> lines title</h2>
    <div class="pgafu-post-categories">category</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Most simple would be move `<div class="pgafu-post-categories">` above `<h2>` in HTML, but it is not possible edit HTML code. Is there a way to do this with css?

Edit: Maybe there is possible also use jquery/javascript to count height of h2 element and then set position to absolute element?

Comment: you want it to be relative to the bottom of the h2 regardless of the h2's height? Probably don't want absolute here, maybe flexbox or grid.

Comment: If you can make `.column` a flexbox (or grid) element (if it isn't already), then you can use `order` to change the order of the children. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: relative to the top of H2, because position of bottom H2 is differently when is one H2 1 line and another on 3 lines. But top position is always same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` and the property `order: 1;` on the children. If you want it to only apply to a specific column you can use the class `column--move-category` on the column in my example. Hope this helps.

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column h2 {
  order: 2;
}

.pgafu-post-categories {
  order: 0;
}

.column--move-category h2 {
  order: 2;
}

.column--move-category .pgafu-post-categories {
  order: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="image-wrapper">image</div>
    <h2>Small title</h2>
    <div class="pgafu-post-categories">category</div>
  </div>

  <div class="column column--move-category">
    <div class="image-wrapper"></div>
    <h2>Long two <br> lines title</h2>
    <div class="pgafu-post-categories">category</div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use flexbox:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child1 {
  order: 2;
}

.child2 {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child1">child 1</p>
  <p class="child2">child 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell me why -1 please. My answer is one of solutions. It is basically the same as another user's answer. I didn't use the questioner's code though. I thought a simple example is better for beginners to understand. If there is something wrong in my code, I would like to fix it.

Comment: From my pov both the answers are correct and yours seems a bit better since it's more simple and can easilly help more people. Users are free to up or downvote but from my pov it's not justified here.

Comment: It would have been better for the global example to use ids instead of class, or better for this specific case use the same class for both and apply the order to first and last child to avoid adding class or ids